# kafka consumer not showing the messages?

Tags: apache-kafka

I created the new topic 'rahul' with the following command :

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic rahul
Created topic "rahul".
```

I also re-checked the topics with

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

__consumer_offsets
    rahhy
    rahul`

Now starting the producer:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic rahul
hey
```

hi
    hello

But when the time comes to consumer to show the messages: there is nothing

[image: no msg retrival in consumer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Kafka 0.9, you don't use Zookeeper for consumption or production

Try `kafka-console-consumer --topic rahul --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

There are other ways you can check messages were sent to Kafka - by checking that the offsets of the topic partitions have changed [using `GetOffsetShell`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-GetOffsetShell)

Comment: How to use `GetoffsetShell` in terminal ? @cricket_007

Comment: still not working...

    `# bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic bfw
>i m ram
>i work at bharat`

But no message receive on consumer part

    `#bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic bfw --from-beginning`

Comment: There must be some other error going on, then. But see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-GetOffsetShell

Comment: I m using kafka-2.11_1.1.0 so I guess its not supporting the `confluence` tools command.

Comment: Confluence is a wiki page... I'm not sure what you mean... That GetOffsetShell command is included in Kafka